# macOS Sierra 10.12.3 iCloud email is STILL in system preferences after signing out

Tags: mac, icloud, macos, apple-id, system-settings

**Story:** Okay, so I have this "old" Mac which was fully signed in and connected to my Apple ID. But now that I have a newer Mac, I want *fully* sign out of the older Mac. So I navigate to `System Preferences>iCloud>Sign out`.

Click Sign out, wait a moment, and it says it signed out.

**Problem:** However when I navigate back to iCloud in System Preferences, inside 1 of the 2 sign-in boxes is my email I use for Apple ID.

[image: iCloud Settings]

I tried everything I could think of, but the stubborn thing just won't forget my email. And I don't like the fact that if someone were to snoop on it, they would have half of the information they need.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well after a few hours of continuously searching for what is causing the problem, I finally found it.

**Solution:** Turns out that I was still somehow connected (Not signed-in) to Game Center inside System Preferences>Internet account. After I deleted that, it finally forgot the Apple ID email.